# How to change SocialAuthenticationFilter.filterProcessesUrl when using SpringSocialConfigurer?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

The Spring Social `SocialAuthenticationFilter` processes the url `/auth`. How can I change this url?
There is a method `SocialAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(String filterProcessesUrl)`. How can I access the `SocialAuthenticationFilter` object to use this method? (I use `SpringSocialConfigurer`, which automatically adds `SocialAuthenticationFilter` to the chain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately using the original `SpringSocialConfigurer` you can't set the processed url. Looking at the code, you may "only" fluently configure things like `postLoginUrl`, `postFailureUrl`, `signupUrl`, `connectionAddedRedirectUrl`, `defaultFailureUrl` and `alwaysUsePostLoginUrl`.

Imho that's an omission in `SpringSocialConfigurer` and you may want to file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/issues.

For the time being, just use the code from `SpringSocialConfigurer` and come up with your own (small) class.

Comment: Thank you - yes, by creating a custom `Configurer` it can be set. I've posted my resulting solution in an additional answer.

Comment: I've also filed an issue on github - [**see here**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/issues/226).

Answer (score 2):

As proposed by user "Hille" I've now created my own `SpringSocialConfigurer` by doing the following:

a) Via github ([see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/2d81e9f3aed457fcf9c2d1a0715790ef6f31f181/spring-social-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/security/SpringSocialConfigurer.java)) I've copied the source code and pasted it into my custom class.
b) Then I could set the `filterProcessesUrl` - here is an example:

```
public class MySpringSocialConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = http.getSharedObject(ApplicationContext.class);
        UserIdSource userIdSource = getDependency(applicationContext, UserIdSource.class);
        UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository = getDependency(applicationContext, UsersConnectionRepository.class);
        SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator authServiceLocator = getDependency(applicationContext, SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator.class);
        SocialUserDetailsService socialUsersDetailsService = getDependency(applicationContext, SocialUserDetailsService.class);

        SocialAuthenticationFilter filter = new SocialAuthenticationFilter(
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class), 
                userIdSource, 
                usersConnectionRepository, 
                authServiceLocator);

        ...

        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/mysociallogin");

        ...

        http.authenticationProvider(
            new SocialAuthenticationProvider(usersConnectionRepository, socialUsersDetailsService))
            .addFilterBefore(postProcess(filter), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }

    private <T> T getDependency(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Class<T> dependencyType) {
        try {
            T dependency = applicationContext.getBean(dependencyType);
            return dependency;
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SpringSocialConfigurer depends on " + dependencyType.getName() +". No single bean of that type found in application context.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to write your code a bit more "springish" and stay with the existing fluent approach, i.e. add `if (filterProcessUrl != null ) {       filter.setFilterProcessesUrl(filterProcessUrl); }` plus an additional setter like `public MySpringSocialConfigurer filterProcessUrl(String filterProcessUrl)` with code analogous to e.g. `userIdSource(UserIdSource userIdSource)`.